# on a complex vector space: $\|x\| = \|y\| \Leftrightarrow x+y$ orthogonal to $x-y$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form, sesquilinear-forms

I want to know if $\|x\| = \|y\|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x+y$ orthogonal to $x-y$.

I was able to prove it for $V$ being a real vector space. However, I'm not able to work it out for complex vector spaces.

Here is the proof for the real case:

(1) suppose $x+y$ and $x-y$ are orthogonal:
$$
0 = \langle x+y,x-y\rangle  = \langle x,x\rangle  - \langle x,y\rangle  + \langle y,x\rangle  - \langle y,y\rangle  = \langle x,x\rangle  - \langle y,y\rangle   = \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2
$$
$\Rightarrow$ $\|x\| = \|y\|$

(2)

The other direction is pretty much the same: $\|x\| = \|y\|$ $\Rightarrow$ $\|x\|^2 = \|y\|^2$
so:  $0 = \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2$ and now the result follows from the equation above in part (1)

Any hints on how to prove it for a complex vectorspace or maybe a counterexample?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \neq 0$ and  $y=ix$. Then,  $\|x\|=\|y\|$. But $\langle x+y, x-y \rangle=2i\|x\|^{2} \neq 0$.
[You have to remember that inner product is conjugate linear in the second variable].

However, $\langle x+y, x-y \rangle= 0$ does imply $\|x\|=\|y\|$ in the complex case also.

Comment: That is a very nice counterexample! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x,y \neq 0$.

$$\lVert x\lVert = \lVert y\lVert \implies (x+y,x-y)=\lVert x\lVert^2 - \lVert y\lVert^2-(x,y)+(y,x)=(y,x)-(x,y)$$

The case of orthogonality $(x,y)=0 \iff (y,x)-(x,y)=0=(x+y,x-y)$

Else If $x,y$ are linearly dependent then exist:

$$\alpha x+ \beta y=0 \implies y=-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}x$$

And from the equal norm we get $$ |\frac{\alpha}{\beta}|=1 \iff \frac{\alpha}{\beta}=e^{i\theta}$$

And $$(y,x)-(x,y)=-(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-  {\frac{\overline\alpha}{\overline\beta} ) } \lVert x\lVert^2=-2i \sin(\theta)\lVert x\lVert^2$$

The case $y= \pm x$ is $  e^{i\theta}= \pm1 \iff \sin(\theta)=0 \implies (x+y,x-y)=0$

$$ (x+y,x-y)=0 \implies  (\lVert y\lVert+\lVert x\lVert)(\lVert y\lVert-\lVert x\lVert) = \lVert y\lVert^2 - \lVert x\lVert^2= (x,y)-(y,x)$$

This is a real number equals an imaginary number. Both must be $0$. Thus, either $(x,y)=0$ or $x = \pm y$  $$\lVert y\lVert-\lVert x\lVert=0 \iff \lVert y\lVert=\lVert x\lVert$$

SO:
If $(x,y)=0$ or $x= \pm y$ then $$\lVert x \lVert = \lVert y \lVert \iff  (x+y,x-y)=0$$